# CSS: Padding issue. Need help please

Tags: html, css, spacing

I'm experiencing a strange CSS spacing issue in Chrome (but not in Firefox and/or IE)

[My site is here.](http://johnedwards.com/news/press-releases/20070905-mattel-recall/)

The vertical spacing in Firefox between the "**Real Estate Search**" (H2 tag) and the form input field for "**San Francisco, CA**" (#city-field input tag) is perfect, but in Chrome, Chrome is applying more/extra vertical spacing than desired.

To help, I've attached a screenshot. The redline represent the extra spacing that Chrome is adding that Firefox/IE are not.

[image]

Any ideas why Chrome is apply more spacing than Firefox & IE.

And how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I'm also using a "reset stylesheet" to standardize across all browsers the H2 spacing, etc. It can be found in my linked HTML document above yet still am experiencing this issue.

Comment: What does Chrome's "Inspect element" and especially its "Metrics" tab say?

Comment: @Pekka, it shows that both the margin-bottom and padding-bottom are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that the line-height is the culprit. Try setting the line height of the h2 to somewhere around 13 to 15 pixels. By default it is set to normal. According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height), line-height: normal "Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based on the font of the element." Firefox and Chrome could be setting different "reasonable" values since they are built on entirely different rendering engines.

Answer (score 1):

Use a reset stylesheet.

Different browsers interpret CSS rules for tags like H1, H2, UL, LI, etc. in different ways. These include padding and default font size. A reset stylesheet takes all those and removes the defaults so that you may substitute your own values when you so desire.

Comment: I have used a reset stylesheet, as seen in the top of my CSS

Comment: (and even using the reset stylesheet as I am, I'm still experiencing these problems)

Answer (score 1):

According to Web Inspector, in Chrome, your input tag has a 2px top and bottom margin. However, Firebug shows no margin for this same input, in Firefox. Use the following in your CSS:

```
#city-field {margin:0}
```

**Edit:** The extra spacing is being caused because the input is set to display:inline-block. If you change it to display:block, you will notice the space disappears. Try using floats and display:block to get the content inline instead.

Comment: I just updated the live code above to use the code you have, it still does not help.

Comment: @JasonTT Okay cool. I've updated my answer with the correct problem, I think.

Comment: if I do #city-field{display:block;}, that does in fact eliminate the extra spacing issue; HOWEVER, that then pushes my submit button to a newline below the city-field input field. Any idea how I can keep the submit button on the same row as the city-field input while also eliminating that funky extra spacing?